# HikariPool shuts down after the app starts

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I built an app to learn to upload files to MySQL. But when i start the app, it shuts down with the exit code 0.
I have tried to run withour `@Query` in the repository. But that did not help either. I have no idea why i am facing this issue. I have seen similar issues on Stackoverflow and tried their solutions too. But that did not help either. Can someone look at the following files tell me where the problem can be?

Below are pieces of my code:

**DocumentStoragePropertiesRepo**

```
package com.media.mediaservice.repository;

import com.media.mediaservice.entity.DocumentStorageProperties;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

public interface DocumentStoragePropertiesRepo extends JpaRepository<DocumentStorageProperties, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT a from DocumentStorageProperties a where a.user_id = ?1 and a.document_type = ?2")
    DocumentStorageProperties findByUserIdAndDocumentType(Integer userId, String docType);

    @Query(value = "Select fileName from DocumentStorageProperties a where a.user_id = ?1 and a.document_type = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    String getUploadDocumentPath(Integer userId, String docType);

}
```

**DocumentStorageProperties**

```
package com.media.mediaservice.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "file")
@Entity
@Table(name = "merchant_documents")
public class DocumentStorageProperties {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "document_id")
    private Integer documentId;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name = "file_name")
    private String fileName;

    @Column(name = "document_type")
    private String documentType;

    @Column(name = "document_format")
    private String documentFormat;

    @Column(name = "upload_dir")
    private String uploadDir;

    public DocumentStorageProperties() {
    }

    public DocumentStorageProperties(Integer userId, String fileName, String documentType, String documentFormat, String uploadDir) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.documentType = documentType;
        this.documentFormat = documentFormat;
        this.uploadDir = uploadDir;
    }

    public Integer getDocumentId() {
        return documentId;
    }

    public void setDocumentId(Integer documentId) {
        this.documentId = documentId;
    }

    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getDocumentType() {
        return documentType;
    }

    public void setDocumentType(String documentType) {
        this.documentType = documentType;
    }

    public String getDocumentFormat() {
        return documentFormat;
    }

    public void setDocumentFormat(String documentFormat) {
        this.documentFormat = documentFormat;
    }

    public String getUploadDir() {
        return uploadDir;
    }

    public void setUploadDir(String uploadDir) {
        this.uploadDir = uploadDir;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DocumentStorageProperties{" +
                "documentId=" + documentId +
                ", userId=" + userId +
                ", fileName='" + fileName + '\'' +
                ", documentType='" + documentType + '\'' +
                ", documentFormat='" + documentFormat + '\'' +
                ", uploadDir='" + uploadDir + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Startup Message:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.7.RELEASE)

2020-05-16 16:03:39.453  INFO 17016 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.MediaServiceApplication            : Starting MediaServiceApplication on Windows7 with PID 17016 (Z:\Programs\Java\Spring\media-service\target\classes started by hnama in Z:\Programs\Java\Spring\media-service)
2020-05-16 16:03:39.459  INFO 17016 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.MediaServiceApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-16 16:03:39.567  INFO 17016 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-05-16 16:03:39.567  INFO 17016 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-05-16 16:03:40.719  INFO 17016 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-05-16 16:03:40.811  INFO 17016 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 79ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-05-16 16:03:41.814  INFO 17016 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-05-16 16:03:41.897  INFO 17016 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final
2020-05-16 16:03:42.195  INFO 17016 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-05-16 16:03:42.739  INFO 17016 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-16 16:03:42.965  INFO 17016 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-05-16 16:03:42.992  INFO 17016 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
2020-05-16 16:03:44.064  INFO 17016 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-05-16 16:03:44.074  INFO 17016 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-16 16:03:44.102  INFO 17016 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-05-16 16:03:45.574  INFO 17016 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6f7008bd, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@433bb228, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@5b1159af, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3af6e7a7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@3873a8af, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@2551c247, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@f29298, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@44a30a94, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@b689143, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@ec96be, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3b740eb0]
2020-05-16 16:03:45.788  INFO 17016 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.m.MediaServiceApplication            : Started MediaServiceApplication in 7.107 seconds (JVM running for 8.378)
2020-05-16 16:03:45.800  INFO 17016 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-16 16:03:45.809  INFO 17016 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-05-16 16:03:45.837  INFO 17016 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>media-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>media-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for uploading/downloading files</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

EDIT:

Here is [log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_dK_rUiSeHWKdhmLsVhG7aC86os6Iulo) file. Its huge so could not add it here.

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:4444/merchant
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.application.name=media-service
spring.main.web-application-type=none
server.port=8080

#trace=true
debug=true

## MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
# Enable multipart uploads
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
# Threshold after which files are written to disk
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
# Max file size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
# Max request size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB
# All files uploaded through the REST API will be stored in this directory
file.upload-dir=C:\\Users\\hnama\\SpringUploads
```

**MediaServiceApplication.java**

```java
package com.media.mediaservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MediaServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MediaServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you set the log level to debug and upload the complete logs?

Comment: @Bandi I have added the logs file link.

Comment: Can we see your `main` method and `application.properties` as well?

Comment: @LucasCampos Added them under EDITS.

Comment: @fist22 is your app just shutting down or restarting? I am asking because of the `spring-boot-devtools` on your `pom.xml`.

Comment: @lucascampos its shutting down. Check the logs above. It starts... And it shuts down.